# Slim3 + Twig Arabic text =?

Tags: twig, slim, arabic, twig-extension, arabic-support

I'm using Slim 3 framework, and Twig view to render the views.

In my view, I have some Arabic text here and there, but when running the application, it shows question marks for the Arabic characters.
the page has a

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

in the header, but doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here's the line with the Arabic Characters:

`<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://mbc-group.com">مجموعة ام بي سي</a>`

Anyone knows if this is related to slim or twig?
Anyone can help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure everything is in UTF-8 encoding, this means all template files, the database and the database connection

Comment: @DarkBee everything is. The characters added are markup in the twig file (not even pulled from DB)

Comment: I don't mean you need to place `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the files, but actualy physically save them with `UTF-8` encoding. It sure aint no `twig`error

Comment: tried to open the file in windows notepad => save as to see the encoding...
The encoding of the file was `ANSI` changed the option to `UTF-8` and tries running the application, but got the same question marks...
Any suggestions?

Comment: What editor are you using that doesn't let you view and change encodings without having to open things in Notepad?